# Screen size/scroll events and Javascript/jQuery timing, updating page issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Javascript function called updatescreen() that performs various actions on page elements.

I call updatescreen() on page load, page scroll, touchmove, orientation and resize. Basically, any time the user is moving things around, I need to update elements to make the page look and function correctly.

Not every trigger actually modifies a page element, but I have to do some checking.

Everything works well, until I start scrolling (or flicking on an iPhone) very quickly. One trigger that happens is that I need to change the position of an element's "top" value (CSS). I have tried this with jQuery "animate" as well as just "css".

If I scroll slowly enough, everything is fine. If I scroll too fast, the script doesn't seem to keep up with my CSS/animation changes, and it ignores the last few, leaving the element in the wrong position. At least, this is what I think is happening.

Is it correct that firing different CSS values at the same element, too quickly, would cause the last ones to be ignored? Are there rules with regards to how jQuery handles this?

Any suggestions on how I could improve this entire workflow?

Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly enough, even after I wrote out this question, I noted that putting values into variables before inserting to the CSS/animate statements seemed to cause this problem.

Comment: Instead, I just put the calculations right into my CSS/animate statement, no variable insert, and that seems to have streamlined the script enough that the problem is going away. Does this make sense?

Comment: So my question now is, variables: not good for performance? I always thought the opposite was the preferred way to do things.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you clarify your question, maybe include some examples? You mention wanting an element to stay at the same position, why not use `position:fixed` ?

Comment: Here is the actual Javascript line: $('div#nav1wrap').animate({'top':'-'+parseInt(nav1height*nav1scrollpercentage)+'px'}, 0);

Comment: I need the element to adjust up or down depending on the position of the scroll, its a percentage of the overall scroll. A little like a parallax effect.

Comment: Hmmm, if you still haven't figured this out can you update your question with your event handler code? I'm not sure I can pinpoint the issue with the given info.

Comment: I guess I solved my own problem, but I'm wondering why storing values in variables in a function would cause such a slowdown in the script executing properly.